# Копирование на телефоне и на компьютере

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

указаны код работает на компьютере но не работает на мобильном. Как его изменить чтоб работал и там и там?

```
$('#button1').on('click', () => {
   let textA = $('#options_sum').html();
   let textB = $('#options_value').html();
   let text = textA + " " + "\n" + textB;
   text = text.replaceAll('&nbsp;', '');
   text = text.replaceAll('<span>', '');
   text = text.replaceAll('</span>', '');
   text = text.replaceAll('<br>', "\n");
   
  

   navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
   
});
```

Comment: Убедитесь что у вас современный мобильный браузер, поддержка [`Navigator.clipbaord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard#browser_compatibility) появилось не так уж и давно на мобильных устройствах, да и на десктопе тоже.

Comment: а нельзя изменить так чтоб и на старых работал?

Comment: Если у вас есть способ работать с буфером обмена без `Navigator.clipboard`, то да наверное...

Comment: что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Я имею в виду то что это нельзя сделать без поддержки `Navigator.clipboard`. (По крайне мере в браузерном JS)

Comment: это я понял. поэтому и спрашиваю, как сделать подругому?

Comment: @ΝNL993, почему это? А как же вариант с `input`?

Comment: @Oliver Patterson
например?

Comment: @OliverPatterson не совсем понял про что ты.

Comment: @OliverPatterson
как я понял ты предложил input?

Comment: По желанию можно 4 почти одинаковые строки заменить одной: `text = text.replaceAll('&nbsp;', '').replaceAll('<span>', '').replaceAll('</span>', '').replaceAll('<br>', "\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с копированием через инпут, раньше использовали этот метод, но он не срабатывает в сниппете кода.

```js
function copyText(value)
{
  const input = document.createElement('input');

  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.value = value;
  
  input.select();
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* for mobail */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  document.body.removeChild(input);
}
```

Comment: Так и знал что ты про `execCommand` говорил)), но это ведь деприкэйтед метод

Comment: будем болтать ради баллов, или поможете решить конкретную задачу?

Comment: @ΝNL993, но он ведь работает... Так в чем проблема? В начале функции можно проверять поддержку `Navigator.clipboard`, и если не доступно - использовать обходной путь из ответа.

Comment: Вы так же можете использовать код из данного поста [@Greg Lowe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript/33928558#33928558)

Comment: @OliverPatterson только что попробовал код из вашего ответа, не работает (не совсем уверен почему P.S. не в сниппете), `но он ведь работает... Так в чем проблема?` - единственная проблема это то что `execCommand` теперь не входит в веб стандарты, а так в общем проблемы нет.

Comment: Другого варианта увы нет.

Comment: @Oliver Patterson
не получается совместить указаны тобой код и мои куд. можешь помочь?

Comment: @Ftrr5, [telegram](https://t.me/CzarOfScripts)